# Input type datetime erro

Tags: php, html, laravel

Boa tarde, eu tenho um problema que não consigo resolver, eu queria mudar o formato do meu formulário para "datetime", porem quando vou testar no meu navegador aparece como se fosse texto.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Data de requisicao</label>
    <input type="datetime" class="form-control" name="data" required><br>
<div class="form-group">
```

[image: Aqui estão as evidencias.]

Comment: Postando o trecho do código fica mais fácil de obter ajuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelas classes da imagem que vc postou percebi que vc está usando ***Boostrap***. Então sugiro esse modelo de `input` data com um `datapicker`

***Precisa desse script para funcionar, pois ele cria um `campo de data` em um `input text`***

```
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js'></script>
<script>
 $('.input-group.date').datepicker({format: "dd.mm.yyyy"});
</script>
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    

          <div class='col-md-3'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="data-pagamento">Datapicker novo</label>
                <!-- Datepicker as text field -->         
                <div class="input-group date" data-date-format="dd.mm.yyyy">
                  <input  type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="dd.mm.yyyy">
                  <div class="input-group-addon" >
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>

    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Plugin pro Datapicker novo -->
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js'></script>
    <script>
     $('.input-group.date').datepicker({format: "dd.mm.yyyy"});
    </script>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu arrumei @hugocsl ... era falta de colocar `https` no endereço ... !

Comment: @VirgilioNovic opá obrigado jovem, eu não sabia que o erro era por causa do protocolo! Tmj

Answer (score 3):

Você deve usar algum desses tipos:

```html
<input type="datetime-local" name="bdaytime">
```

ou

```html
<input type="date" name="bday" >
```

1. email
2. datetime-local

fonte:https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp

Comment: Nenhum dos dois tipos funciona...

Answer (score 2):

A tag **input type="date-time"** foi descontinuado:

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime

E foi substituída pela tag **input type="datetime-local"**:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local

```js
document.getElementById("datetime").defaultValue = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
```

```html
<html>
<body>
 <input id="datetime" type="datetime-local">
</body>
</html>
```

**Obs:** Não funciona no I.E e no Firefox: Chrome OK; Opera OK;

O tipo **input type="date"** tem suporte no firefox apartir da versão 57.0, no Chrome desde a 22;

```js
document.getElementById("datetime").value = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <input id="datetime" type="date">
</body>

</html>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/data

> Considerações: Ainda têm muitas inconsistências nestes inputs o input
>   **type="datetime-local"**, o DOM properties *defaultValue* funciona somente no firefox, no chromium  não funciona mas o DOM properties
>   *value* funciona.
>
> O input **type="date"** o DOM porperties *value* não funciona no
>   firefox também não funciona no Chromium.

E ai, no seu navegador funcionou?

Answer (score 1):

segundo este artigo da mozilla o input do tipo "datetime" é obsoleto, e seu uso não é encorajado:
 https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime

Comment: Pois eu já tinha lido esse artigo porem nenhum dos outros funcionam

Comment: @Humbertovieira o que realmente você quer fazer.

Comment: queria que aparecesse um tipo de calendário para escolher o ano o mesmo e o dia

Comment: Da uma lida na minha resposta pra você ver pelo HTML têm muita inconsistência o chrome não aceita defaultValue, somente value;  Sugiro que você utilize algum framework;

Comment: cara, usa um plugin então, bootstrap datetime picker, ja que vc ta usando bootstrap no seu projeto